# Google Maps SDK for Android loading empty map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've tried to use Google Maps SDK for Android in my app and some users are saying they are loading an empty map.

It looks something like this: https://i2.paste.pics/FAUVC.png

However, I'm not able to reproduce the problem myself. In theory, location permissions are not required to load the Map SDK. I've checked my API key in the Google Cloud Platform Console and found all of my responde codes have been 2xx so far.

Would anyone have any ideas on what this issue might be?

Comment: Did you add your API key in your app? 
You have to add the key in your app's manifest:

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR-KEY" />

Comment: Are you able to check if you've entered your API key within the `google_maps_api.xml` file in the release directory `(/app/src/release/res/values)` just like in your debug directory `(/app/src/debug/res/values)`?